# Test web connection by a socket-client in my vue 3 composition API app

Tags: socket.io, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, stream-socket-client

I'm making a vue 3 app, I'm starting with a web connection test visiting the official [web](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-vue) guide, but I don't reach the goal to test it through the socket-client.io package. How do I do this?. This is what I've done about it, I need to make a socket to a external website (There is no need to have a backend part to make this possible or a sample):

- I put the Socket.ts at the root of the project.

  ```
   import { reactive } from 'vue'
   import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

   export const state = reactive({
     connected: false
   })

   export const socket = io('https://www.google.com')

   socket.on('connect', () => {
     state.connected = true
   })

   socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     state.connected = false
   })
  ```
- then I'm using it in my component:

> ```
> <script setup lang="ts">
> import { state } from '../Socket'
> import { socket } from '../Socket'
> const connected = computed(() => {
>   return state.connected
> })
> onMounted(async () => {
> console.log
>   socket.connect()
> })
> </script>
> <template>
> <p> {{ connected}} </p>
> </template>
> ```

Comment: there could be a lot of reasons including the backend part. i would suggest to prepare a sample working project and share it for example on replit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export const socket = io('https://www.google.com')` part seems... improbable.
See [socket.io Troubleshooting: Problem: the socket is not able to connect](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#problem-the-socket-is-not-able-to-connect)

> You are trying to reach a plain WebSocket server

If you are testing out socket.io, I would suggest setting up a simple socket.io server locally, and then connecting to it from your Vue app.
`npm install express socket.io`, and, in a new folder, create a `server.js` file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New client connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(4001, () => console.log(`Listening on port 4001`));
```

Then you can change the address in your Vue app to `http://localhost:4001`:

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

export const state = reactive({
  connected: false
})

export const socket = io('http://localhost:4001')

socket.on('connect', () => {
  state.connected = true
})

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  state.connected = false
})
```

Now you should see a log message in the server console when your Vue app connects to the server.